# ImageMagick, delegate failed

Tags: imagemagick, converters, image-conversion

I'm trying to use ImageMagick to convert a bunch of PDF into JPG (or PNG) but this error keep happenings.

```
convert E/paginas/pdf/E2.pdf E/paginas/pdf/E2.png
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-qX48YuZM-00000001' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
convert: Postscript delegate failed `E/paginas/pdf/E2.pdf':  @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/663.
convert: missing an image filename `E/paginas/pdf/E2.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3015.
```

Same to .jpg

PS: I'm at Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Someone votes to close it as Off-topic, but if this ins't a development problem. I don't know what this was. REALLY THANK YOU!

Comment: This is actually a Ghostscript error, not ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 just successfully converted a PDF-1.4 file to .png format. What version are the PDFs you're using, and what version of convert?

You determine the PDF version with: `head -c 8 myfile.pdf`

The ImageMagick version: `convert --version`

What you can do to diagnose the problem is to `apt-get source imagemagick`, and use the source line numbers in the error messages to locate the problem, and possibly fix the program to recognize the PDF, even if you have to tell the program to ignore certain sections.

Comment: could you send me one of the PDFs? jc at unternet dot net.

Comment: email. that's my email address: jcomeau arroba unternet punto net

Comment: same issue here - anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: the OP never sent me his file, so I couldn't test it. will you?

Comment: jComeau, unfortunately the file I'm dealing with is copy-written and cannot be shared. It seems related to a font or encoding setting not recognized by Ghostscript. The file with issues on my end has the following issues when converting via the command line:
File has an invalid xref entry:  11.  Rebuilding xref table.
**** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
**** The file was produced by: 
**** >>>> Mac OS X 10.6.8 Quartz PDFContext <<<
**** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
**** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
**** specification

Comment: Although perhaps un-related, I figured out my issue. The /tmp/ directory was too small for processing the PDF at the sizes I was requesting. If anything I'd check the /tmp/ directory size and watch the conversion files being created there, when you run the php conversion.